# open multiple CSV files and reshape it to column

Tags: python, export-to-csv, reshape

i have multiple CSV files and want to reshape them to column and save each files as CSV again.
i wrote this code but cant import multiple CSV once.

first, i opened the file like this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
results = []
with open("ESACCI-SEALEVEL-L4-MSLA-MERGED-19930115000000-fv02.csv") as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
for row in reader: # each row is a list
    results.append(row)
```

and then reshape it and save as csv

```
data1 = np.reshape(results,(-1, 1))
np.savetxt('data1.csv', data1 , delimiter=",")
```

please help me

Comment: Hi, I don't exactly understand the issue here. Do you want to process a list of filenames?

Comment: Hi, i want to import multiple csv files then reshape each files to column and save every file as csv again separately.

Comment: So is there something wrong with just using a for loop and doing them one by one?

Comment: ok, how should i use for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for-loop to achieve this

```
import csv
import numpy as np

input_file_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.cvs']

for file_name in input_file_list:
    results = []
    with open(file_name) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
    for row in reader: # each row is a list
        results.append(row)
    data1 = np.reshape(results,(-1, 1))
    np.savetxt(output_name[:-4] + 'processed.csv', data1 , delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to do the same operation on multiple csv files. This can be done using a loop like below where you can mention the directory and the file-name pattern for the csv files -

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import glob, os

os.chdir("C:\\your_dir\\")
results = []
for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
        for row in reader: # each row is a list
            results.append(row)
```